# Mount FAT32 partition (external drive) on Mac

Tags: hard-drive, partition, external-disk, ntfs, fat32

I have an external disk drive of 2TB with two partitions, one NTFS and another with FAT32 format.

The NTFS partition is automatically mounted when i plug the device using Paragon NTFS but I  don't know how to mount the FAT32 partition.

Can someone help me with this?
[image: This is what diskutil list shows on terminal]

More info:
Here is what windows shows on Disk Management when i plug the external disk
[image: Windows screenshot]

Comment: What do you get when you issue the command `gpt show -l /dev/disk1`

Comment: I get:
`gpt show: /dev/disk1: Suspicious MBR at sector 0`
`gpt show: error: bogus map`
`gpt show: unable to open device '/dev/disk1': Undefined error: 0`

Comment: I have a feeling (meaning I can't test my theory at present) that your Paragon software is causing the issue.  Do you have another Mac you can try to mount this drive on?  Or, as a solution, can you copy all the data (in Windows) to two separate folders, reformat as MBR/FAT32 and then copy everything back?

Answer (score 16):

```
mkdir /fat_mount
# create area to mount FAT partition
mount -t msdos /dev/diskXXX /fat_mount
```

^ Thats how to mount fat drives/partitions in Mac OS, also useful for single user mode recovery. Note I think some versions may ship with "mount_msdos" as opposed to using "mount -t msdos" but I haven't used enough to say for sure.

Comment: That `/fat_mount` directory will be created on root directory?

Comment: Also.. what's `/dev/diskXXX` will be? according to `diskutil list` results i mean

Comment: /fat_mount is an empty directory on root, its just where your disk will be mounted (and accesed) , acording do your output it would be /dev/disks1s3 (I guess if you wanted to mount the FAT parition of XBOXGAMES. (or try /dev/disks1s2) Although your diskutil screendump and GUI screen dump show conflicting information.

Comment: i got the result `mount_msdos: /dev/disk1s3: No such file or directory`

Comment: according to your screenshots your should be using /dev/disk1s4

Comment: How do you unmount it?

Comment: This worked for me when `diskutil mount` failed. I had to run with root permissions (`sudo`).

Answer (score 5):

Try "diskutil mount /dev/disk1s2" in terminal (without quotes) and it should mount that drive for you.

Comment: That is the NTFS disk, not the fat32 one

Comment: Can you connect the drive without using Paragon, and run diskutil list again and post the results?

Comment: It shows the same... i have uploaded a screenshot from windows to show that the fat32 partition is there.

Comment: When you have the NTFS partition mounted, does it report the same size as what you see in windows, or does it report a 2TB size?

Comment: It reports 2TB size

Answer (score 0):

FAT16 and FAT32 partitions are mounted automatically. I have the same issue with Paragon NTFS driver installed. Although on another Mac without Paragon it get mounted automatically.

Comment: I don't have Paragon NTFS installed. It also does not mount automatically.